Is it a good practice to import functions from __main__.py?
My __main__.py module for my package is defined like so (simplified):
def main():
    ... # Start my GUI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It is also a package, with an __init__.py as follows:
from .__main__ import main

__all__ = ["main"]

And a setup.py (relevant portion):
setup(...,
      entry_points={
          "gui_scripts": [
              "xpuz-ctk = xpuz.__main__:main"
          ]
      }
)

Should I be doing this or is there a better way?

See What is __main__.py.   I believe the if __name__ == "__main__" check is redundant within the __main__.py file.  Not entirely sure if contents of then answers in that post will answer your question. I'm still reading through them all myself. I think the import isn't needed, but it may depend on exactly how the package is invoked.

@nigh_anxiety I've read through that post, it doesn't help much. I believe I do need the guard as I import it in __init__.py. But there should hopefully be a better way.

@tomasvana10 Why do you need it in __init__.py at all? If you really need it shouldn't it be defined in __init__.py and imported in __main__.py?

Ensure that main is intended to be used both as an entry point for the package and as part of the package's public API. If main is only intended to start the GUI, it may not be necessary to expose it through init.py.
